# Confused about lifetimes

Tags: rust

I have a struct of type `SCGI` that has a property `Netstring` which is itself another struct:

```
struct SCGI<'a> {
    content_length:uint,
    scgi:bool,
    request_method:RequestMethod,
    request_uri:&'a str,
    body:&'a str,
    original:Netstring
}       
impl<'a> SCGI<'a> {
    …
}
```

If this was C++, I'd want `Netstring` to be a new object, not a reference to another object. But if I try to build my code, I always get the following error:

> *error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0*

Adding a lifetime to `original` doesn't help: `original:&'a Netstring` results in the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post the full error message emitted by the compiler, including the code that it highlights? Also, can you post the definition of the `Netstring` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your full example, but I think you only got the syntax wrong (check the `<'a>` after the type).

This code compiles for me:

```
struct Netstring<'a> {
  a: &'a str
}

struct SCGI<'a>{
  content_length: uint,
  scgi: bool,
  body: &'a str,
  original: Netstring<'a>
}
```

Hope it helped.